# Strange issue with Scandit SDK on scanning 1D barcodes

Tags: ios, swift

There is a problem in Scandit SDK on scanning 1D barcodes. For 2D barcodes,​ it works perfectly but when I try to scan 1D - it does not recognize any of the codes.

I've googled a lot and found that I have to set active symbols count to 20, what I tried:

```
let symbologySettings = settings.settings(for: .code39)
symbologySettings.activeSymbolCounts = Set(7...24) as Set<NSNumber>
```

and by this, all my settings look like this:

```
let settings = SBSScanSettings.default()
settings.highDensityModeEnabled = true

let symbologies: Set<SBSSymbology> = [.datamatrix, .ean13, .ean8, .upce, .qr, .code39, .code128, .twoDigitAddOn, .fiveDigitAddOn]
for symbology in symbologies {
    settings.setSymbology(symbology, enabled: true)
}


let symbologySettings = settings.settings(for: .code39)
symbologySettings.activeSymbolCounts = Set(7...24) as Set<NSNumber>

symbologySettings.setExtension(SBSSymbologySettingsExtensionFullAscii, enabled: true)
```

So by this, I was expecting that the problem will be fixed but it still exists. Is there anything that I can do to fix that problem?

Barcode:

[image: Barcode]

Comment: Can you add an example of a non-working barcode to your question? It would help diagnose the problem.

Comment: @Codo Sure! I do not have enough reputation for attachments, but here it is: `https://imgur.com/79M6mlQ`

Comment: I've tested your barcode with the *Scandit Barcode Scanner* app from the AppStore. It decodes it as *Code 39*: "A+A-1234" (symbol count: 10). I don't think you need to configure anything special for Code 39. Does your code have sufficient white space around it? The image in the question above can be successfully scanned; the image on imgur.com cannot be scanned because it's shown with no surrounding white space on a black background.

Comment: @Codo even when I scan from this Stack page it does not recognize it. I do not know what the issue is